# Objective-C file i/o error

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, io, filehandle

```
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender
{
    NSString* conversationFile = [@"~/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"conversation.txt"];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:conversationFile];

    if (fileExists == FALSE)
    {
        [self doShellScript:@"do shell script \"cd ~/; touch conversation.txt\""];
    }

    NSString *conversationContent = [[NSString alloc] stringWithContentsOfFile:@"~/conversation.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSString *myMessage = [[messageBox stringValue]copy];

    NSString *combinedContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ \r\n %@", conversationContent, myMessage];
    [[[myConversationBox textStorage] mutableString] setString: combinedContent];
    [combinedContent writeToFile:@"~/conversation.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

}
```

The above code presents the following error

> 2011-07-07 21:38:08.703
>   iMessages[86493:903]
>   -[NSPlaceholderString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x100111690
>
> 2011-07-07 21:38:08.704
>   iMessages[86493:903]
>   -[NSPlaceholderString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x100111690

Comment: what happens if you change the line after if statement to be:     NSString *conversationContent = [[NSString alloc] stringWithContentsOfFile:conversationFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

Comment: Do you mean prior to the if statement? It is already after..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` is a class method of `NSString`, not an instance method, so you don't need to (shouldn't) alloc it first.

```
NSString *conversationContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"~/conversation.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: Try passing an NSError object to the `writeToFile` method and see what error you are getting.

Comment: Okay, I'm stupid. Figured out to with the output of Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 UserInfo=0x1004a7b90 "The file “conversation.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." Underlying Error=(Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory")

Comment: So, where did my directory handling slip up?

Comment: I don't think that you can use the ~ in your path without expanding it.  Use `stringByExpandingTildeInPath` on your NSString object.

Comment: I tried `NSString *pathToFile = [@"~/conversation.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSString *conversationContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];` which still wont work and throws the error: Error: NSMenu

Comment: If you NSLog pathToFile or view it in the debugger, what does it contain?  Also, your error got truncated in your last comment.

Comment: The error was: "Error: NSMenu". The output for pathToFile was directly on target: "/Users/EvanSchoffstall/conversation.txt"

Comment: Oh that was stupid I forgot to change "writeToFile: @"~/conversation.txt""to  "writeToFile:pathToFile" which did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `initWithContentsOfFile` in place of `stringWithContentsOfFile` or remove the `alloc` call. So have:

```
NSString *conversationContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"~/conversation.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

or

```
NSString *conversationContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"~/conversation.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```